# How to change the Panel-caption CSS?

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin7

I want to change the CSS of the Panel header (caption). But I do not know how to perform that.

I want to replace the class `v-panel-caption` by my own class

```
<div class="v-panel v-widget v-has-width v-has-height"> 
   <div style="margin-top: -37px;" class="v-panel-captionwrap">
      <div class="v-panel-caption">
         <span>My caption</span>
      </div>
   </div>
...
</div>
```

TO

```
<div class="v-panel v-widget v-has-width v-has-height"> 
   <div style="margin-top: -37px;" class="v-panel-captionwrap">
      <div class="my-panel-caption">
         <span>My caption</span>
      </div>
   </div>
...
</div>
```

The solution could be to define a primary style :

```
public class myPanel extends Panel {

    public  myPanel() {
        this.setCaption("My Caption");
        this.setContent(new Label("test");
        this.setPrimaryStyleName("my-panel-caption");
    }
}
```

But that change only the global `<div>`:

```
<div class="v-panel-my-panel-caption my-panel-caption"> 
   <div style="margin-top: -37px;" class="v-panel-captionwrap">
      <div class="v-panel-caption">
         <span>My caption</span>
      </div>
   </div>
...
</div>
```

There is any way to customize the panel caption CSS ? Or should I compose, myself, a new layout (maybe using CssLayout) ?

The only way I have found is using the CSS !important tag :

```
.my-panel-caption {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
  padding: 0 12px !important;
  line-height: 36px !important;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #23C344 !important;
  background-color: #4F9EE5 !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  font-weight: 400 !important;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) !important;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0 !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

But I don't like that :(

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Usually, I add a custom style name to the component and then re-define styles. E.g.: `.my-panel .v-panel-caption { background-color: red; }` ... this should work without the `!important`.

Comment: In fact I just want to custom this panel for a specific page. Not for all of them.

Comment: Ok sorry, I am stupid :)

Comment: You ask questions, this is not stupid :)

Comment: Please share your solution when done.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
in .java :

```
myPanel.setStyleName("customStyle");
```

and in .css :

```
.v-panel-caption-customStyle {
    text-align: center !important;  
}
```